# C# LINQ OrderBy on sub array

Tags: c#, linq

With C# LINQ, can we only OrderBy on a range of elements of List and keep others in place?

For example, input list is {"a","b","c","d","e"}, an imagined OrderByDescending is like :

```
OrderByDescending(delegate d,int start_index,int end_index)

l=l.OrderByDescending(x=>x,1,3).ToList();
```

The result is:{"a","d","c","b","e"}

Without this function, I need to split/LINQ Orderby/rejoin which lose the spirit of LINQ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Skip` and `Take` to achive that.

```cs
var input = new[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };

var res = input.Take(1)
               .Concat(input.Skip(1).Take(3).OrderByDescending(e => e))
               .Concat(input.Skip(4));
```

and you can also make an Extension Method like this

```cs
public static class IEnumerableExt
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> OrderRangeByDescending<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> input, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, int from, int length)
    {
        return input.Take(from)
                    .Concat(input.Skip(from).Take(length).OrderByDescending(keySelector))
                    .Concat(input.Skip(from + length));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TSource> OrderRangeBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> input, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, int from, int length)
    {
        return input.Take(from)
                    .Concat(input.Skip(from).Take(length).OrderBy(keySelector))
                    .Concat(input.Skip(from + length));
    }
}
```

```cs
var input = new[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };

var res = input.OrderRangeByDescending(e => e, 1, 3);
```

Answer (score -1):

Calling `Skip` and `Take` repeatedly may have a performance impact, especially if the source is generated by intensive computation. An optimal solution would require that the reading of the source will occur only once. This can by achieved by splitting the source in multiple enumerables, but using a single enumerator. Having such a Splitter would allow us to implement the `OrderRangeBy`/`OrderRangeByDescending` methods quite easily:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> OrderRangeBy<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    int startIndex, int endIndexExclusive)
{
    var parts = source.Split(startIndex, endIndexExclusive);
    return parts[0].Concat(parts[1].OrderBy(keySelector)).Concat(parts[2]);
}

public static IEnumerable<TSource> OrderRangeByDescending<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    int startIndex, int endIndexExclusive)
{
    var parts = source.Split(startIndex, endIndexExclusive);
    return parts[0].Concat(parts[1].OrderByDescending(keySelector)).Concat(parts[2]);
}
```

Here is an implementation of the Splitter:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource>[] Split<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, params int[] indices)
{
    var parts = new IEnumerable<TSource>[indices.Length + 1];
    var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < indices.Length; i++)
    {
        parts[i] = GetPart(indices[i]);
    }
    parts[indices.Length] = GetPart(Int32.MaxValue);
    return parts;
    IEnumerable<TSource> GetPart(int maxIndexExclusive)
    {
        if (index >= maxIndexExclusive) goto finish;
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return enumerator.Current;
            index++;
            if (index >= maxIndexExclusive) break;
        }
        finish: if (maxIndexExclusive == Int32.MaxValue) enumerator.Dispose();
    }
}
```